# How to refer to order aggression on PineScript from TradingView?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to create some indicators that use the market aggression for the analysis, but I don't know how to refer to these aggressions on the PineScript editor (what function to call, parameters, etc).

By "aggression" I mean the market orders executed, example:
For a random stock/future contract, if there are 1000 limit buy orders on the offer book at price 20.00, and a seller steps in and executes 300 of those orders at 20.00 (the seller sent 300 market sell orders), there will be 700 limit buy orders left on the offer book. There has been a 300 order aggression on the Sell Side.

So for each bar there will be a value of Buyers Aggressions and Sellers Aggressions.

Any idea how to refer to that data on the Pine Editor?